# Only last line from txt file is put into the array

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have an issue with my code. I'm trying to read line by line from a txt file and then add those lines into a list. My issue is that only the last line of the file is added into the list.

This is my code for the scanner:

```
public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        cyclistList = (List) Arrays.asList(line);
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

I can print the list out just fine, but when I try to add line by line from the txt file into the list, it just adds the LAST line.

This is what the txt file contains and is also printed out with the `System.out.println` method:

```
[A.CONTADOR TCS ESP 00:09:48    2   45]
[A.DELAPLACE    BSE FRA 03:11:28    1   15]
[A.DEMARE   FDJ FRA 04:05:28    0   43]
[A.FONSECA  BSE FRA 03:53:13    0   18]
[A.GENIEZ   FDJ FRA 03:42:57    27  31]
[A.GERARD   BSE FRA 04:02:06    0   0]
[A.GREIPEL  LTS ALL 04:03:28    0   366]
[A.GRIVKO   AST UKR 02:38:06    0   51]
[A.HANSEN   LTS AUS 03:45:18    0   2]
[A.KRISTOFF KAT NOR 04:01:06    0   90]
[A.LOSADA   KAT ESP 02:32:30    0   7]
[A.MALORI   MOV ITA 03:37:28    0   11]
[A.TALANSKY TCG USA 00:22:06    22  32]
[A.TIMMER   TGA HOL 04:05:30    0   0]
[A.TULIK    EUC FRA 03:18:24    0   11]
[A.VALVERDE MOV ESP 00:05:25    72  103]
[A.VUILLERMOZ   ALM FRA 01:28:29    2   52]
[A.YATES    OGE GBR 02:16:36    17  42]
[B.COQUARD  EUC FRA 03:42:36    0   152]
[B.FEILLU   BSE FRA 03:23:11    0   17]
[B.HUZARSKI BOA POL 03:38:06    1   27]
[B.JUNGELS  TFR LUX 01:33:21    16  76]
[B.MOLLEMA  TFR HOL 00:15:14    0   38]
[B.NAULEAU  EUC FRA 04:40:12    0   2]
[B.TANKINK  TLJ HOL 02:30:12    0   0]
[B.VAUGRENARD   FDJ FRA 03:43:08    0   20]
[C.FROOME   SKY GBR 00:00:00    119 139]
[C.GAUTIER  EUC FRA 01:51:51    4   54]
[C.LAPORTE  COF FRA 03:59:10    0   17]
[C.RIBLON   ALM FRA 02:48:19    1   23]
[D.CARUSO   BMC ITA 02:26:32    8   21]
[D.CIMOLAI  LAM ITA 04:33:21    0   34]
[D.GAUDIN   ALM FRA 04:16:13    0   0]
[D.GRUZDEV  AST KAZ 04:01:12    0   0]
[D.MARTIN   TCG IRL 02:03:37    27  72]
[D.NAVARR GARCIA    COF ESP 02:43:34    0   9]
[D.OSS      BMC ITA 03:22:14    0   16]
[D.TEKLEHAIMANOT    MTN ERY 02:16:15    8   51]
[D.VAN BAARLE   TCG HOL 04:18:40    0   13]
[D.WYSS     BMC SUI 02:37:17    0   0]
[E.BOASSON HAGEN    MTN NOR 03:08:02    2   79]
[E.BUCHMANN BOA ALL 03:08:47    16  15]
[F.BRUN     BSE FRA 04:10:32    0   18]
[F.POZZATO  LAM ITA 03:58:20    1   0]
[F.SENECHAL COF FRA 04:04:06    0   -5]
[F.VACHON   BSE FRA 03:15:01    0   11]
[G.CARUSO   KAT ITA 03:17:03    0   1]
[G.IZAGIRRE MOV ESP 01:41:34    28  26]
[G.PREIDLER TGA AUT 03:14:14    15  14]
[G.RAST     TFR SUI 03:29:00    0   0]
[G.SOUPE    COF FRA 03:55:35    0   34]
[G.THOMAS   SKY GBR 00:31:39    22  37]
[H.ZUBELDIA TFR ESP 02:36:50    0   0]
[I.ERVITI   MOV ESP 03:47:14    0   6]
[I.STANNARD SKY GBR 03:59:37    0   0]
[J.ARREDO MORENO    TFR COL 03:56:49    0   10]
[J.BAKELANTS    ALM BEL 01:16:36    2   50]
[J.BARTA    BOA RTC 01:26:56    20  47]
[J.CASTROVIEJO  MOV ESP 01:26:05    0   31]
[J.DEBUSSCHERE  LTS BEL 04:16:06    0   29]
[J.DEGENKOLB    TGA ALL 03:39:43    1   298]
[J.FUGLSANG AST DAN 01:25:23    64  34]
[J.GUARNIERI    KAT ITA 04:22:20    0   24]
[J.HERRADA  MOV ESP 02:40:06    3   1]
[J.JANS RENSBURG    MTN AFS 02:18:16    0   0]
[J.MENDES   BOA POR 04:07:47    0   0]
[J.PANTANO  IAM COL 01:09:08    2   48]
[J.PERAUD   ALM FRA 02:35:10    0   -5]
[J.RODRIGUEZ    KAT ESP 01:36:07    78  71]
[J.ROY      FDJ FRA 03:32:12    6   8]
[J.SERPA PEREZ  LAM COL 03:54:25    0   20]
[J.SIMON    COF FRA 03:19:53    12  18]
[J.VAN EMDEN    TLJ HOL 03:54:19    0   11]
[J.VERMOTE  EQS BEL 03:50:32    0   0]
[K.DE KORT  TGA HOL 02:57:05    0   30]
[K.DURASEK  LAM CRO 03:02:14    13  26]
[K.KOREN    TCG SLV 02:51:44    1   14]
[K.VANBILSEN    COF BEL 04:41:27    3   37]
[L.BAK      LTS DAN 01:56:57    14  9]
[L.DURBRIDGE    OGE AUS 04:25:03    0   11]
[L.KONIG    SKY RTC 02:53:09    0   0]
[L.MATE MARDONES    COF ESP 02:10:12    0   29]
[L.ROWE     SKY GBR 04:04:45    0   3]
[L.TEN DAM  TLJ HOL 03:18:43    0   -5]
[L.WESTRA   AST HOL 03:03:09    3   25]
[M.BONO     LAM ITA 03:52:17    0   0]
[M.BRANDLE  IAM AUT 04:37:36    0   9]
[M.CAVENDISH    EQS GBR 04:12:05    0   206]
[M.CHEREL   ALM FRA 01:05:00    24  8]
[M.ELMIGER  IAM SUI 03:26:47    0   0]
[M.FRANK    IAM SUI 00:15:39    4   24]
[M.GOLAS    EQS POL 03:21:17    0   9]
[M.HALLER   KAT AUT 03:59:04    1   13]
[M.IRIZAR   TFR ESP 03:19:44    0   0]
[M.GHEBREMEDHIN MTN ERY 03:10:36    0   26]
[M.LADAGNOUS    FDJ FRA 02:53:22    9   13]
[M.MATTHEWS OGE AUS 04:26:33    0   25]
[M.QUINZIATO    BMC ITA 03:53:21    0   0]
[M.ROGERS   TCS AUS 01:56:13    1   32]
[M.SCARPONI AST ITA 02:05:03    0   0]
[M.SCHAR    BMC SUI 02:31:13    1   1]
[M.SIEBERG  LTS ALL 04:24:52    0   11]
[M.TOSATTO  TCS ITA 04:01:15    0   0]
[M.TRENTIN  EQS ITA 03:50:59    1   44]
[M.WYSS     IAM SUI 02:34:38    0   0]
[N.EDET     COF FRA 03:42:42    16  34]
[N.OLIVEIRA LAM POR 02:15:32    0   10]
[N.QUINTANA MOV COL 00:01:12    108 80]
[N.ROCHE    SKY IRL 01:54:08    0   16]
[P.FEDRIGO  BSE FRA 02:22:54    0   37]
[P.MARTENS  TLJ ALL 03:04:52    0   20]
[P.PERICHON BSE FRA 03:05:48    0   61]
[P.QUEMENEUR    EUC FRA 02:57:19    0   46]
[P.ROLLAND  EUC FRA 00:17:30    74  73]
[P.SAGAN    TCS SLQ 02:14:55    3   432]
[P.VOSS     BOA ALL 03:24:53    0   7]
[P.WEENING  OGE HOL 04:15:20    0   -5]
[R.BARDET   ALM FRA 00:16:00    90  74]
[R.CURVERS  TGA HOL 03:35:40    0   46]
[R.DENNIS   BMC AUS 03:27:34    1   36]
[R.GESINK   TLJ HOL 00:10:47    32  53]
[R.HESJEDAL TCG CAN 02:04:37    41  43]
[R.HOLLENSTEIN  IAM SUI 02:58:30    0   0]
[R.JANS RENSBURG    MTN AFS 03:21:30    0   14]
[R.KREUZIGER    TCS RTC 01:02:51    12  17]
[R.MAJKA    TCS POL 01:35:06    40  28]
[R.NAVARDAUSKAS TCG LIT 04:14:40    20  44]
[R.PLAZA    LAM ESP 01:38:22    11  86]
[R.PORTE    SKY AUS 02:16:05    58  38]
[R.SICARD   EUC FRA 01:51:32    23  32]
[R.URAN     EQS COL 02:08:20    5   55]
[R.VALLS FERRI  LAM ESP 03:03:11    0   5]
[S.CHAVANEL FDJ FRA 04:56:59    2   39]
[S.CLEMENT  IAM HOL 02:33:42    0   37]
[S.CUMMINGS MTN GBR 03:12:23    2   49]
[S.DEVOLDER TFR BEL 04:21:31    0   0]
[S.GESCHKE  TGA ALL 01:58:14    22  78]
[S.KRUIJSWIJK   TLJ HOL 01:21:27    10  10]
[S.PAUWELS  MTN BEL 00:31:03    55  43]
[S.SANCHEZ  BMC ESP 00:22:50    0   10]
[S.TUFT     OGE CAN 04:48:08    0   0]
[S.VANMARCKE    TLJ BEL 03:31:15    8   5]
[S.YATES    OGE GBR 03:16:04    0   40]
[T.DE GENDT LTS BEL 02:48:02    6   90]
[T.FARRAR   MTN USA 04:32:32    0   12]
[T.GALLOPIN LTS FRA 01:40:44    8   85]
[T.KANGERT  AST EST 01:24:58    0   0]
[T.LEEZER   TLJ HOL 04:26:47    0   0]
[T.MACHADO  KAT POR 02:54:31    0   0]
[T.PINOT    FDJ FRA 00:38:52    82  113]
[T.VOECKLER EUC FRA 02:14:08    23  28]
[T.WELLENS  LTS BEL 03:59:39    0   -1]
[V.NIBALI   AST ITA 00:08:36    53  49]
[W.ANACONA  MOV COL 02:31:14    33  29]
[W.BARGUIL  TGA FRA 00:31:15    0   25]
[W.KELDERMAN    TLJ HOL 03:04:07    1   20]
[W.POELS    SKY HOL 02:12:44    18  9]
[Y.GENE     EUC FRA 04:04:56    0   0]
[Z.STYBAR   EQS RTC 03:30:13    0   78]
```

This is the output I get with the `cyclistList = (List) Arrays.asList(sc.nextLine());` code:

```
[Z.STYBAR   EQS RTC 03:30:13    0   78]
```

**EDIT:**
My bad, I forgot to add something. I do already have a list in the class:

```
private List<RacingCyclist> cyclistList = new ArrayList<>();
```

This list implements a Comparable:

```
public class RacingCyclist implements Comparable<RacingCyclist> {
//...
}
```

So the method `cyclistList.add();` does not work, as I get the following error:

> "No suitable method found for add(String) Method
>   Collection.add(RacingCyclist) is not applicable (argument mismatch;
>   String cannot be converted to RacingCyclist)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, you're creating a new `List` every single time on your loop.

Here's the problem: `cyclistList = (List) Arrays.asList(line);`. On this line you create a new `List`, and that's why you're holding only the last element, because on the last iteration you have created a list with only that element.

To solve it, change this:

```
public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        cyclistList = (List) Arrays.asList(line);
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

To this:

```
public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(line);
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

That way you'll have a single `ArrayList` with all of your data, instead of creating a new `List` every iteration.

---

**EDIT:** From your edit, you're trying to add a `String` to your `ArrayList` of a custom Object, which in your case is `RacingCyclist` (Or is this a custom list? If it is you're trying to create a List of Lists).

If this Object can hold a `String`, then it should probably have a getter and a setter, so use them inside your loop like:

```
customObject.setLine(line);
cyclistList.add(customObject);
```

Now if your custom Object is another list (why?) then it should probably hold other objects that can hold a `String`, or it could hold the `String` itself. But my guess is that you probably shouldn't be doing this, use a simple `ArrayList` instead with holder objects that implements `Comparable`, that way the `ArrayList` will be able to sort your elements.

---

**Second edit:** Ok, I've made a few modifications on your custom class. Here it goes.

**RacingCyclist.java**

```
package opg3_tour;

/**
 *
 * @author erso
 */
public class RacingCyclist implements Comparable<RacingCyclist> {

    private String name;
    private String team;
    private String country;

    private String time;
    private int mountains;
    private int points;

    public RacingCyclist(String name, String team, String country, String time, int mountains, int points) {
        this.name = name;
        this.team = team;
        this.country = country;
        this.time = time;
        this.mountains = mountains;
        this.points = points;
    }

    // Empty constructor.
    public RacingCyclist() { }

    // Getters

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public int getMountains() {
        return mountains;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    // Setters - They update the data on your Object.

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setTeam(String team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void setMountains(int mountains) {
        this.mountains = mountains;
    }

    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

// This method parses lines on the following format: [A.CONTADOR TCS ESP 00:09:48    2   45]
    public void parseLine(String str) {
        str = str.replaceAll("^ +| +$| (?= )", ""); // Removing extra spaces between words.
        str = str.replace("[","");
        str = str.replace("]","");
        String[] lines = str.split(" "); // Breaking the String into lines.

        setName(lines[0]);
        setTeam(lines[1]);
        setCountry(lines[2]);
        setTime(lines[3]);
        setMountains(Integer.parseInt(lines[4]));
        setPoints(Integer.parseInt(lines[5]));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + team + " " + country + " " + time + " " + mountains + " " + points + "\n";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(RacingCyclist o) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(getTime()) > Integer.parseInt(o.getTime())){ 
            return 1;
        }
        else if (Integer.parseInt(getTime()) < Integer.parseInt(o.getTime())){
            return -1;
        }
        else  {
            return this.name.compareTo(o.name); 
        }
    }
}
```

I've created an empty construtor and a method called `parseLine(String line)` which can take that line of your file and assign the values to your custom object `RacingCyclist`.

Then, your loop should look like this:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    RacingCyclist obj = new RacingCyclist();
    obj.parseLine(line);
    cyclistList.add(obj);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

That way you'll create a new instance of your `RacingCyclist` object, and the `parseLine` method will break that String down and get its values and assign it to your object internal variables.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add something, please take a look at the edit :)

Comment: @SquishyAura Take a look now.

Comment: Sorry heh, it's a school assignment we got today, so I'm having some issues understanding what to do about it. When I type my custom object (which is RacingCyclist I assume): RacingCyclist.setLine(line);                    I get the following error cannot find symbol, method setLine(String).
I do also have a toString method to return the name, team, country and so on.

Comment: It was just an example, it was not supposed to be used as it is hehe. I mean, it would be better for us if you showed the entire class.

Comment: Alright, here is the RacingCyclist class: http://paste.ofcode.org/YzQ7DHnZQeFxTd4sZfpXmd

Here is the main class:
http://paste.ofcode.org/Lr2ZdPek548yJvENzR2fpZ

And thanks a lot for your time btw :)

Answer (score 2):

That is becuase you are no adding to the list (using "add" method) but creating an new list all the time.